# Making UI Components Selectable in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a few UI Components in React JS, which render some HTML on screen, like below:

```
<div class="content-block margin-10">
  <h1 class="block-head">Heading Text</h1>
  <div class="section-text bg-gray text-md">Section Text</div>
</div>
```

On screen, this is displayed as proper HTML. What I want is the ability for the user to be able to select (by clicking) this block, which should display the element tree along with the classes applied to each element on one side of the page. Then, my goal is to allow users to change the classes applied to see how the UI changes with the change in classes.

I want to be able to do this react/javascript without using any library such as grapesjs.

Can you please guide me on how I can go about achieving this?

Update: One thing I did is that I added a function `onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}` to the block div.

Now within handleClick, I could get the element's classed:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log('E', e.target.classList);
    e.target.classList.add(styles.borderline);
}
```

Now the problem is, if there are multiple blocks on the page, how will I know which block is selected? Eventually, I want to save/replace the data related to the block in my database. So, I need to be able to know which block was updated, and save its data.

Comment: Can you use JQuery ?

Comment: Either react or pure javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three parts to this solution:

1. Stateful class values
2. Displaying the tree
3. Binding the stateful class values to inputs

**(1)**
Using functional components with React hooks, you can initialize a variable for each default class name with the `useState` hook as follows:

```
const [containerClass, setContainerClass] = useState("content-block margin-10");
const [headingClass, setHeadingClass] = useState("block-head");
const [sectionClass, setSectionClass] = useState("section-text bg-gray text-md");
```

This sets their default values to the values in the question description and ensures that when these values are updated, any HTML that depends on these values will re-render. Thus, in order to bind these to the elements in question, we can use the following `className`s as opposed to their hard-coded counterparts:

```
<div className={containerClass}>
  <h1 className={headingClass}>Heading Text</h1>
  <div className={sectionClass}>Section Text</div>
</div>
```

**(2)**
Displaying the tree requires three things of us: a boolean variable that indicates whether or not the tree is displayed, a click event (as noted in the question) that toggles this variable, and a JSX section that renders when the variable is true.

The variable itself can be a simple `useState` declaration like the ones above:

```
const [treeIsDisplayed, setTreeIsDisplayed] = useState(false);
```

It can be toggled by using the following function as the container `div`'s `onClick` value:

```
const toggleTree = () => setTreeIsDisplayed((prev) => !prev);
```

And we can render the tree conditionally like so:

```
{treeIsDisplayed && (
  <div>
    <p>
      {"<div class="}
      <input value={containerClass} />
      {"></div>"}
    </p>
    <p>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{"<h1 class="}
      <input value={headingClass} />
      {"></h1>"}
    </p>
    <p>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{"<div class="}
      <input value={sectionClass} />
      {"></div>"}
    </p>
    <p>{"</div>"}</p>
  </div>
)}
```

This renders as the following:

[image: rendered tree]

Note: The tree will display *under* the HTML by default, so some CSS will be needed to display it to the side.

**(3)**

We can now create functions to be utilized by the above inputs to set the class names dynamically:

```
const changeContainerClass = (e) => setContainerClass(e.target.value);
const changeHeadingClass = (e) => setHeadingClass(e.target.value);
const changeSectionClass = (e) => setSectionClass(e.target.value);
```

And we set the `onChange` value of each input to its corresponding change function.

All together, the working solution constructed here looks like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [containerClass, setContainerClass] = useState("content-block margin-10");
  const [headingClass, setHeadingClass] = useState("block-head");
  const [sectionClass, setSectionClass] = useState("section-text bg-gray text-md");

  const [treeIsDisplayed, setTreeIsDisplayed] = useState(false);

  const toggleTree = () => setTreeIsDisplayed((prev) => !prev);

  const changeContainerClass = (e) => setContainerClass(e.target.value);
  const changeHeadingClass = (e) => setHeadingClass(e.target.value);
  const changeSectionClass = (e) => setSectionClass(e.target.value);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={containerClass} onClick={toggleTree}>
        <h1 className={headingClass}>Heading Text</h1>
        <div className={sectionClass}>Section Text</div>
      </div>
      {treeIsDisplayed && (
        <div>
          <p>
            {"<div class="}
            <input value={containerClass} onChange={changeContainerClass} />
            {"></div>"}
          </p>
          <p>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{"<h1 class="}
            <input value={headingClass} onChange={changeHeadingClass} />
            {"></h1>"}
          </p>
          <p>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{"<div class="}
            <input value={sectionClass} onChange={changeSectionClass} />
            {"></div>"}
          </p>
          <p>{"</div>"}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var elementTree;

function convertToHTML(tree) {
  let elementTree = `<table>`;

  elementTree += `
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Element Tree</th>
            <th>Classes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>`;
  tree.map((element, elementIndex) => {
    elementTree += `
          <tr>
            <td>${element.element}</td>
            <td>
              <textarea onchange=changeClass(event) data-target='${elementIndex}'>${element.classList.join(" ")}</textarea>
            </td>
          </tr>`;
  });

  elementTree += `</table>`
  return elementTree;
}

function changeClass(event) {
  let textArea = event.target;
  let oldClass = textArea.defaultValue.trim().split(" ");
  let newClass = textArea.value.trim().split(" ");
  let index = textArea.dataset.target;
  if (oldClass[0]) {
    elementTree[index].target.classList.remove(...oldClass)
  }
  elementTree[index].target.classList.add(...newClass)
  console.log(oldClass, newClass);
}

function getElementTree(event) {
  var target = event.target,
    elementTree = [];
  while (target) {
    let classList = target.classList;
    elementTree.unshift({
      element: target.tagName,
      classList: target.classList.value.split(" "),
      target: target
    });
    target = target.parentElement;
  }
  console.log(elementTree);
  return elementTree;
}

function showElementTree(tree) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("element-tree")[0].innerHTML = tree;
}

document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  elementTree = getElementTree(event);
  let elementTreeHTML = convertToHTML(elementTree);
  showElementTree(elementTreeHTML);
}, false);
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.main>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

table,
th,
tr,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="content-block margin-10">
      <h1 class="block-head">Heading Text</h1>
      <div class="section-text bg-gray text-md">
        <p>element tree</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element-tree">

  </div>
</div>
```

A vanilla JS solution would be to use eventHandlers and hold the target variable. Whenever the class changes the associated classList property of the target object is changed

Comment: Thanks. This is a really nice solution. When a user clicks/hovers an element, is there a way to put a border to that element showing the selection?

Comment: Probably the simplest way to do that would be to add a class when the user clicks or hovers either using vanilla event listeners or, since you're in React, the `onClick` and `onHover` properties. You can then of course style the class in CSS. A word of warning for that; you might consider using `outline` instead of `border` there, since `border` will add to the width and height of the element, and that can create unexpected effects. `outline` does not have that effect.